# r - get variable name after eval/parse or get

Tags: r, parsing, get, eval, assign

I can create a variable from text, this if from a loop, where I am going to have several `x` values

```
fx_1 <-function(varname)
{
  print(paste("fx_1|variable:",deparse(substitute(varname)),"| value:",paste(varname,collapse = "@")))
}

sapply(c("var1","var2"),function(x){
  assign(paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS"),c("test","with","getevalparse",x))
  fx_1(eval(parse(text=paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS"))))
  fx_1(get(paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS")))
})

[1] "fx_1|variable: eval(parse(text = paste0(\"Example_Module_\", x, \"_IDS\"))) | value: test@with@getevalparse@var1"
[1] "fx_1|variable: get(paste0(\"Example_Module_\", x, \"_IDS\")) | value: test@with@getevalparse@var1"
[1] "fx_1|variable: eval(parse(text = paste0(\"Example_Module_\", x, \"_IDS\"))) | value: test@with@getevalparse@var2"
[1] "fx_1|variable: get(paste0(\"Example_Module_\", x, \"_IDS\")) | value: test@with@getevalparse@var2"
```

However in my loop I will need to pass this variable to a function that uses deparse(substitute()) to name the output-files, similar to the function `fx_1` above. I was naively hoping to recover something the `Example_Module_1_IDS`

```
Example_Module_1_IDS=c("test","with","var")
fx_1(Example_Module_1_IDS)
[1] "fx_1|variable: Example_Module_1_IDS | value: test@with@var"
```

`as.symbol` didn't work either, so I was wondering if there is a way to do this?

**Edit** Added the function `fx_1` and the loop example

Comment: Doesn't just `paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS")` return what you want? I'm confused. Usually using `get/assign` is a indicator that a poor R design decision has been made. It's way easier to use named lists. You can `Example_Module_IDS<-list(c("test","this","code"))` and use `Example_Module_IDS[[1]]` or `Example_Module_IDS[[x]]` to get that list out.

Comment: Yes `paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS")` returns what I wanted, perhaps my example wasn't completely clear without my `fx_1` and the loop. I added those now, I had my `fx_1` earlier and I loved to use the same variable for the data and variable names (used for output files) but perhaps I have to do things differently now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you are headed down a bad path here. It seems like you are storing important information in the variable name itself which isn't really something that most programming languages like. Better to separate the name from the value. But if you are in control of `fx_1`, you can change it to take the value and name separately, and even have it default to the `deparse()` value for most "normal" cases. For example

```
fx_1 <-function(var, varname=deparse(substitute(var))) {
     paste("fx_1|variable:",varname,"| value:",paste(var,collapse = "@"))
}
fx_1(x)
# [1] "fx_1|variable: x | value: 1@2@3"
fx_1(get("x"), "x")
# [1] "fx_1|variable: x | value: 1@2@3"
```

There's no amount of `get()` or `eval()` in a function call that will change that the variable "looks like" to a function. If you need to manipulate parameter names, you'd need to use a function like `do.call()`. For example

```
sapply(c("var1","var2"),function(x){
  varname <- paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS")
  assign(varname ,c("test","with","getevalparse",x))
  do.call("fx_1", list(as.symbol(varname)))
})
```

which returns

```
                                                                         var1 
"fx_1|variable: Example_Module_var1_IDS | value: test@with@getevalparse@var1" 
                                                                         var2 
"fx_1|variable: Example_Module_var2_IDS | value: test@with@getevalparse@var2"
```

But again, the more common and easier to work with solution involves named lists

```
Example_Module_IDS <- Map(function(x) c("test","with","getevalparse",x), c("var1","var2"))
Example_Module_IDS[["var1"]]
Example_Module_IDS[["var2"]]
printnv <- function(n, v) paste("fx_1|variable:",n,"| value:",paste(x,collapse = "@"))
mapply(printnv, names(Example_Module_IDS), Example_Module_IDS)
```

Comment: Wow, this is very instructional, thanks for answering beyond my question. This is a good lesson. Even though @StatnMap answer my literal question I think I should accept this answer instead so people in the future go for the best practices

Answer (score 0):

The plan is thus to have an output like :

```
"fx_1|variable: Example_Module_var1_IDS | value: test@with@getevalparse@var1" 
"fx_1|variable: Example_Module_var1_IDS | value: test@with@getevalparse@var2"
```

With a function with two variable, it is easier. (I also removed the print):

```
fx_2 <-function(varname, value)
{
  paste("fx_1|variable:", varname, "| value:", paste(value, collapse = "@"))
}

sapply(c("var1","var2"), function(x) {
  value <- c("test","with","getevalparse",x)
  varname <- paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS")
  fx_2(varname, value)
})
```

And here the solution with one parameter. I corrected the "get" so that it looks in the parent environment:

```
fx_1 <-function(varname)
{
  paste("fx_1|variable:",varname,"| value:", 
        paste(get(varname, envir = parent.frame()),collapse = "@"))
}

sapply(c("var1","var2"), function(x) {
  assign(paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS"), c("test","with","getevalparse",x))
  fx_1(paste0("Example_Module_",x,"_IDS"))
})
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the type of output I want, but when I run your code I got  `Error in get(varname) : object 'Example_Module_var1_IDS' not found` which I think comes from `get` inside `fx_1` resolving this variable that is not defined in the scope of the function

Comment: Probably a problem with environments. If I change the function to take two variables, it is easier. I edited above.

Comment: And I edited again the function `fx_1` so that `get` take the value of `Example_Module_var1_IDS` in the parent environment